# Problem with Publishing my App in F-Droid

Tags: android, fdroid

I have an android project named [SimpleVideoEditor](https://github.com/fahimfarhan/SimpleVideoEditor), and I would like to submit it into F-Droid. So I was following this [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) tutorial by F-Droid. Now in the [building-it](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-it) subsection, they say

```
Make sure that `fdroid lint app.id` doesn't report any warnings. If it does, fix them.
```

So I tried `$ fdroid lint com.fahimfarhan.simplevideoeditor` and it gave me this error:

#### Error

```
com.fahimfarhan.simplevideoeditor: Build generated by `fdroid import` - remove disable line once ready
```

At first I didnot even know that this is an error and so I submitted my app. But later I got an Email that says my build failed. So I am trying to fix it. 
What does this error even mean? I don't understand how to fix this issue. I did Google but the search result doesnot make any sense. Sorry for not including anything else because this is all I have. I am confused.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm facing the same issue. @Qazi Fahim Farhan

Comment: @ritwikshanker No, I couldn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to this problem.
Their must be a line inside build in your `yaml` file which might be something like this.

```
disable: Generated by import.py - check/set version fields and commit id
```

You have to remove this line and then you will pass all the lint errors. Your builds list should look something like this.

```
Builds:
  - versionName: '2.0'
    versionCode: 2
    commit: commitId
    subdir: app
    gradle:
      - yes
```

The auto generated looks something like this -

```
Builds:
  - versionName: '2.0'
    versionCode: 2
    disable: Generated by import.py - check/set version fields and commit id
    commit: '?'
    subdir: app
    gradle:
      - yes
```

Remove the disable line and add the commit and you will be good to go.

Comment: HI. Thanks for your answer. After following your steps, now I get this error:``` ERROR: Could not build app com.fahimfarhan.simplevideoeditor: OSError while trying to execute /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gradlew-fdroid clean: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gradlew-fdroid' ``` . So a `gradle-fdroid` file is missing from my system I guess. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Which OS are you using? They only support Linux. Can't find the link right now but they listed it somewhere(will update if I find it). You can try building by pushing your code to gitlab which will in turn run a build on pushed code.

Comment: I am using Debian 10 testing. Thanks for your help.